# Sharing knowledge articles between multiple data categories

Tags: trigger, role-hierarchy, lightning-knowledge, visibility, data-category

I am trying to solve a use case for which I need expert advice whether the solution I am thinking is good or there is any better solution available.

Customer is having below data categories –

[image]

Default Data Category Visibility = None.

Here is the role hierarchy -

[image]

Each Department is having mainly two personas –

- Knowledge Author
- Knowledge Manager

Note – Customer is using Lightning Knowledge

Requirement is that when each department will create their knowledge articles they will associate data categories -

- Data Categories which belongs to their department means that article is only visible within departments
- Data Categories – “All” means that article is visible to entire university

But here is the twist, they want some of their documents to make visible to other departments. Like document created by Department – “Computer Science”, but should be visible to Department – “Electronics”.
Now I can’t give the role visibility to other department’s data categories that will make all the documents visible from other department.

So this is what I am solutioning –
I am creating a multiselect picklist with values as Computer Science, Information Technology, Electronics.
Now when Knowledge Author will create the articles, they will chose which departments they want to share this document with.
And based on that Apex trigger will associate the data categories with the below code –

```
List <String> objType = new List<String>();
objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
List<knowledge__DataCategorySelection> allDataCategorySelections = new List<knowledge__DataCategorySelection>();
List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objType); 

for(Knowledge__kav a : knowledgesToBeShared){
String[] sharedWith = a.Shared_With__c.split(';');
for(String sharedWithSingle : sharedWith){
       knowledge__DataCategorySelection single = new knowledge__DataCategorySelection();
       single.DataCategoryGroupName = describeCategoryResult.get(0).getName();
       single.ParentId = a.Id;
       if(sharedWithSingle.equalsIgnoreCase('All')){
            single.DataCategoryName = 'All';
       }else if(sharedWithSingle.equalsIgnoreCase('Computer Science')){
            single.DataCategoryName = 'Computer_Science';
       }else if(sharedWithSingle.equalsIgnoreCase('Information Technology')){
            single.DataCategoryName = 'Information_Technology';
       }else if(sharedWithSingle.equalsIgnoreCase('Electronics')){
            single.DataCategoryName = 'Electronics';
       }
       allDataCategorySelections.add(single);
}
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I did for a client! The only corner case is you not deleting knowledge__DataCategorySelection records when the picklist is unselected. My suggestion is to clarify this as part of the requirement and also take into consideration Trigger.old to efficiently sync. picklist and data category selection.

Comment: Yes that's something I also need to do. But thank you for the comment. It gives me some confidence now.